# node.js - read first 'x' lines of csv file

Tags: node.js, csv

I'm using the node-csv module (http://www.adaltas.com/projects/node-csv/) to read a csv file. On every row, I do a check for a condition, and want to stop reading the file if the condition is false. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says to end your csv pipeline if I understand that correctly:

end()

Terminate the parsing. Call this method when no more csv data is to be parsed.